# Function parameter "not declared in this scope". Parameter is visible in h file

Tags: c++, mongodb

Here is the code for reference
http://pastebin.com/nr7wuxNA

I'm testing some calls with the C++ driver for mongo

It works except when I add this line

```
obj.appendBinData( "binTest",sizeof(test), BinDataGeneral, test);
```

Here is the error message

```
ninexample.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
ninexample.cpp:73:48: error: ‘BinDataGeneral’ was not declared in this scope
     obj.appendBinData( "binTest",sizeof(test), BinDataGeneral, test);
                                                ^
ninexample.cpp:73:48: note: suggested alternative:
In file included from /usr/include/mongo/db/jsobj.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/mongo/client/connpool.h:23,
                 from /usr/include/mongo/client/dbclient.h:32,
                 from ninexample.cpp:22:
/usr/include/mongo/bson/bsontypes.h:102:9: note:   ‘BinDataGeneral’
         BinDataGeneral=0,
         ^
```

I'm pretty new to C++ so I'm not sure why there is an error here since it seems to see the type BinDataGeneral in the h file.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Thanks!

Comment: What library is this that you're using?

Comment: Never mind, I just compoiled the stuff myself: http://dl.mongodb.org/dl/cxx-driver; It runs fine with the mongo:: qualification: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6254057/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is looking for `BinDataGeneral`, but it can't resolve that symbol.

Try `mongo::BinDataGeneral`.

Comment: Yup that fixes it indeed.